# Watir-webdriver screenshot write to html file

Tags: screenshot, watir, watir-webdriver

I created a method that takes a screenshot and then writes to an html file, inserting that screenshot into a table.

When I used Watir it worked fine (only really used IE browser).

Now I am using Watir-Webdriver and it takes the screenshots (on Firefox) and saves them just fine. However, when I write them to the html file they just show up on my html page as the little ripped paper icon.

This is my method:

```
def LogCapture(testID, passFail)

@passFail = passFail
@testID = testID
@time = Time.now.strftime("%m.%d.%Y %H.%M.%S")
@shotLoc = $FolderPath + "\\" + @passFail + @time + ".png"
$browser.screenshot.save @shotLoc

$fileHtml.puts"<TR><TD><@testID + " " + @passFail + " " + @time + "></TD></TR>"
$fileHtml.puts"<TR><TD><img src='" + @shotLoc + "'></TD></TR>" 
$log.info(@passFail)

end
```

I know that the Watir-Webdriver screenshots capture the entire length of the page, unlike Watir, but I have no idea why the screenshots are failing to display on my html file/page.

Thanks y'all

*SOLUTION: got it to display in both FF and IE when writing to the html file I just had to include:
    "file:\\localhost\" 
before my file path.

Thanks Justin! Go Maple Leafs!

Comment: I assume the "little ripped paper icon" means that the html file is not finding the required image. Did you validate that the html in the fileHtml output is correct and that the image exists where it should?

Comment: That is what I assumed as well but I checked and it does have the correct path in the output.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you saying the report works when generated using watir-classic instead of watir-webdriver? Can you share the html of the file generated? Also, what browser are you viewing the output in?

Comment: I still really don't know why but the images are not broken when viewing in IE. BUT, if I try to view to html file in firefox the images are still  broken

Comment: I believe in firefox, you need to prefix the file path in the src with "file:///". For example "file:///C:/folder/image.jpg". But then I think it will only work in Firefox and not in IE. I guess you need to pick a single browser to view the report in.

Comment: You can also use relative uri. (And I think it is better : you will be able to send the whole report with pictures to someone to show it)

Comment: Oh ok sounds awesome. well if my source is "C:\\Users\\jetthehawk\\Documents\\WatirTests\\PostMigrationTests\\ScreenLogs\\PASSED. Logged In.06.07.2013 13.14.03.png" 

what would my relative URI be?

Comment: If your html file is in C:\Users\jetthehawk\Documents\WatirTests\Report => You should use ..\PostMigrationTests\ScreenLogs\PASSED. Logged In.06.07.2013 13.14.03.png

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to save screenshots in base64 format instead of saving to PNG file as it works around all path issues and easy keeps history:

```rb
screenshot = $browser.screenshot.base64
$fileHtml.puts "<img src='data:image/png;base64,#{screenshot}'>"
```